# Windows 8.1 suspends all running processes

Tags: process, windows-8.1

This has happened to me twice now. Windows 8.1 decides to suspend all my processes all of a sudden. Now I know that it does that to Metro apps that are in background. But my regular desktop apps (including Explorer) might be exempted from that, I guess (especially when I'm currently using them).

I could get it to run again more or less by starting Task Manager via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, then killing Explorer and starting Process Explorer from there which enabled me to resume all processes again. But I still wonder how this happens in the first place. Specifically I'd like to ask whether that's in any way expected behaviour and what I could do to prevent it from occurring in the future.

My system is virus-free, just in case anyone asks. Yesterday I just tried to run `msbuild`; after hitting <kbd>↲</kbd> above issue happened. A while ago I don't remember what I tried to do when it manifested, but I didn't think far enough to solve the problem with `procexp` and ended up restarting the machine.

**EDIT:** Okay, it seems like starting msbuild triggers this behaviour. No idea why, though.

**EDIT2:** Apparently only when running it from Far Manager (actually, it's a batch file for me, which calls the `vsvars32` batch and runs `msbuild` afterwards. It runs fine from `cmd` or PowerShell.

**EDIT3:** Updating Far Manager to its latest version changed nothing. However, running `msbuild` directly (not through the batch file) worked even from Far.

For completeness:

- [Far Manager](http://farmanager.com)
- My `PATH` includes the directory `D:\Users\Joey\Batches` which contains a batch file `msbuild.cmd` with the following contents:

  ```
  @echo off
  call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
  msbuild %*
  ```
- Then, running `msbuild` from within Far seems to produce this problem. At least for me, reliably.

Comment: Does this problem happen every time you run msbuild?

Comment: No. I merely mentioned it just in case anyone asks what I was doing. I doubt the application is relevant here.

Comment: You need to tell us what triggers this behavior.

Comment: If I knew, I'd be a few steps further already. From what I can tell nothing specific I did.

Comment: @Ramhound: It indeed seems to be `msbuild`. I could reproduce the problem twice in the last half hour. Not once did `msbuild` run normally.

Comment: Do you have something a large msbuild task by chance?  Because I have no problem running msbuild by itself nor any of my tasks.

Comment: It happens already when I run it in a directory where no solution or project file exists. Everything locks up even before it prints anything to the console.

Comment: @Joey, What do you  mean when you say *"starting Process Explorer from there"*?

Comment: @Pacerier: Launching Process Explorer from Task Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with [clink](http://code.google.com/p/clink/issues/detail?id=170&can=1&sort=-id). It has been fixed by now, but only in source, not in a release.